# What are some natural remedies for lowering blood sugar besides diet and exercise?

Tags: diabetes, natural-remedy, type-2-diabetes, blood-sugar, glycated-hemoglobin-hba1c

I was diagnosed as a type 2 diabetic a few months ago, and have been dieting and exercising ever since. My A1C has gone down from 13% to 9%, I noticed these cinnamon pills in a local store that claimed they helped naturally bring down blood sugar. So I am wondering now if there is any validity in that, and also if there are any other natural ways to bring down blood sugar besides prescribed medication (which I am taking) and exercise.

Comment: @CountIblis - please do not answer in comments.

Comment: Congratulations on a job very well done!

Comment: UPDATE

     So it turns out I was actually misdiagnosed, I am a in fact a type 1 diabetic. I only found out after my health kept going down even with Metformin and dieting. I am the only person in my family to have been diagnosed. Thank you for all the suggestions, now that I am on proper insulin treatment, things are getting a lot better.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be on a great track. I think you're doing all the right things.

Regarding cinnamon pills: I have indeed read studies regarding cinnamon curbs blood sugar by lowering insulin resistance. Just be aware that it is a warming herb/spice so if you are someone that finds themselves just a bit too hot all the time, this will exacerbate that.

Lastly, here are some other natural remedies that could work, with some support from science:

1. Coptis extract (called Huang Lian in Chinese): Lengthy studies have shown that Coptis extract has antibacterial, antiviral, and anti-inflammatory properties and protect against diabetes, heart disease, and some forms of cancer very well. (source: [[US National Library of Medicine National Institutes of Health](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4609856/))
2. Gynostemma Pentaphyllum Herbal Tea: Gynostemma has been shown in a study to decrease insulin resistance significantly (Source: [US National Library of Medicine National Institutes of Health](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20213586))

Note: I work with a new shop that addresses health concerns, including diabetes: [rootandspring.com](https://rootandspring.com/collections/internal-health/diabetes) and I'm also one of the authors for rootandspring.com, which believes and carries in both these products.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). This is a great answer, but I would suggest that you add a note to warn the OP and other users to take care of appropriate dosage, side effects, potential interactions and contraindications, especially for the extract of Coptis, whose active compounds for this indication are mostly alkaloids. While mentioning the business you are affiliated with is most certainly allowed, it should serve only to support the answer; therefore I took the liberty of moving it to the end, to let your outstanding answer shine. Hope to see more from you.